# Typescript why omit same key with different type strictness

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I was reading through Ant Design source code, and I stumbled upon something in the Button component part of the code. (For simplicity I will be removing interface / type keys which are not useful for the question).

It starts by defining `ButtonTypes` which is a string union:

```
type ButtonTypes = 
  | 'default'
  | 'primary'
  | 'ghost'
  | 'dashed'
  | 'link'
  | 'text'
```

It then defines a `BaseButtonProps` `interface` which will be used to define the `type` of an `object` containing the button's `props`.

```
export interface BaseButtonProps {
  type?: ButtonType;
}
```

It then creates a `type` that can accommodate for all attributes that could be added to a HTML anchor button element.

```
export type AnchorButtonProps = {
  href: string;
} & BaseButtonProps &
  Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<any>, 'type'>;
```

To do this it uses an intersection `type` between an `object` containing `href`, my `BaseButtonProps` `type` and `Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<any>, 'type' | 'onClick'>;` Where `React.AnchorHTMLAttribute<T>` is:

```
interface AnchorHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    href?: string | undefined;
    type?: string | undefined;
}
```

Why does `AnchorButtonProps` `Omit<>` the `type` `key` from `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes`?

Initially, I thought this could be due to the fact that `type` in `BaseButtonProps` is of `type` `'default' | 'primary' | 'ghost' | 'dashed' | 'link' | 'text' | undefined` while on `AnchorHTMLAttributes` it is of `type` `string | undefined`. I thought `Omit<>` was used so that type would be remain specific and not default to `string | undefined`. Yet, I have tried the same intersection without the `Omit<>` and the results are the same, `type` is of `type` `ButtonTypes` and will not accept just any string as with `string | undefined`. [Here's the code with the `Omit` commented out in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgCEBXGGCAOwBVb6BeAgCZJMKJgBsY+OAB8CYKKBRRqU2fgDmACwgBnSTMEodmpANUExwdgGtz+GEgAekiuSeRYcKw6gi09BiMkZlYOAAUcMB04AG9yOAS4GjoAfgAuRhY2Lh4KAF9Kd2h4ZPoAQXY0bSgQ7IiIKLh+OMS4TSJMDL0FdnV8uAAyRiDa8MjogfjEgHoAKgB5EGAYAB5Z6cRiGAA6CqroAAlOAFkAGTLWBQAjFiQdFZR2agA+ODmAGjgAclKv5-XXEI0GIlPQxEh4I4MntqqN2PUohRHNtSk0CGQ3hsVrx+ABRKA4KAZbh0b74fBfLzRdgQeBGHTAdTsFBXcFJCBJHhkoQicT6NTyRTKOxaXT8wzGUx2Sw2OwOZzmJjsHlWUxfbYACgATABmLVagCU5CAA) showing that it won't allow assigning just any string.

Comment: The answer to #1 is probably "yes." No idea what the answer to #2 is, unless it was needed in previous versions of TypeScript but not current ones.

Comment: Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Nl21rW) have the same issue?  I'm trying to eliminate the react dependency before I wade in too much (since I don't know enough about react to speak confidently about it).  If so, then I have no idea why that `Omit` is in there.  [It doesn't do anything to the resulting type](https://tsplay.dev/w8xr9w), at least with the example code.  If it really doesn't have any effect, then I'm wondering if there's any possible way to answer authoritatively, since presumably only those who wrote the code know why they did it.

Comment: Yes, this is my exact error. It might be due to the fact that something has changed within the latest versions, and that Omit<> is no longer needed.